# Replace and flat Numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have ndarray with shape `(2,1)`.
Every element is a ndarray with shape `(4)`
I want to make a dataframe with shape `(2,4)`

currect shapes:

```
df.shape = (2,1)
df[0].shape = (1,)
df[0][0].shape = (4,)
```

for example:

```
df[0][0] = [1 2 2 4]
df[1][0] = [1 1 1 1]
```

I want its will look like this:

```
df[0] = [1 2 2 4]
df[1] = [1 1 1 1]
```

Comment: `df[0] = df[0][0]` and `df[1] = df[1][0]`?

Comment: have you tried to use `df.flatten()` or `df.squeeze()`

Comment: @Albo yes, like this

Comment: @MatteoPeluso not working

Comment: `df2 = pd.DataFrame([df[0][0].copy(), df[1][0].copy()])` might help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you have an object dtype array (but why is it called `df`?):

```
In [150]: df = np.empty((2,1),object)                                                                           
In [151]: df[0,0] = np.array([1,2,2,4])                                                                         
In [152]: df[1,0] = np.array([1,1,1,1])                                                                         
In [153]: df                                                                                                    
Out[153]: 
array([[array([1, 2, 2, 4])],
       [array([1, 1, 1, 1])]], dtype=object)
In [154]: df.shape                                                                                              
Out[154]: (2, 1)
In [155]: df[0].shape                                                                                           
Out[155]: (1,)
In [156]: df[0,0].shape                                                                                         
Out[156]: (4,)
```

`np.concatenate` (or one of the `stack` derivatives) can join a list/iterable of arrays, provided they match in size.

`stack` applied directly to `df` doesn't work, because it is (2,1) shaped:

```
In [157]: np.stack(df)                                                                                          
Out[157]: 
array([[array([1, 2, 2, 4])],
       [array([1, 1, 1, 1])]], dtype=object)
```

But if we first ravel (or squeeze) the array so it is (2,) shape:

```
In [158]: np.stack(df.ravel())                                                                                  
Out[158]: 
array([[1, 2, 2, 4],
       [1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape((2, 4)).T)

df
   0  1
0  1  1
1  2  1
2  2  1
3  4  1
```

Or:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(a.reshape((2, 4)))

df
   0  1  2  3
0  1  2  2  4
1  1  1  1  1
```

Comment: yes , but I can't reshape like this because 'a' is shape of (2,1) and not (2,4)

Comment: @KorenLevenbrown Your shape seems to be `(2, 1, 4)`. Right?

Comment: No. my shape looks like (2,1) (1,) (4,)

Comment: @KorenLevenbrown Can you please share the example of actual data instead of just shape?

Answer (score 0):

You could use another dataframe to rearrange and then set it back, like:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([df[0][0], df[0][1]])
df = df2
```

---

**UPDATE**: concerning the comment from @Koren Levenbrown

```
df = np.array([df[column][0] for column in df])
```

is another solution

Comment: Thanks, not exactly, but you help a lot

Comment: Can you tell which part is to improve, then I'll try to do it tomorrow

Comment: a = np.array([np.asarray(x[0]) for x in a)

Comment: You mean `df = np.array([df[column][0] for column in df])`?